# C# DataGridView Insert and Delete selected row

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I've connected my SQL Database to a C# project in Visual Studio. In a comboBox I get the names of the tables from the database, and when I click a button it shows me the content of the current table in a DataGridView. I want to know how can I save/delete date from a row that is selected?

Ps: The tables have different names and different columns and I need some save/delete buttons to work for all

Answer (score 1):

You could add buttons to the DataGridView and use the CellContentClick event.
That's how you add buttons:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn editButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
editButton.HeaderText = "Update";
editButton.Text = "Update";
editButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
editButton.Width = 80;
dbgViewObj.Columns.Add(editButton);//dbgViewObj is your datagridview control
DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
deleteButton.HeaderText = "Delete";
deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
deleteButton.Width = 80;
dbgViewObj.Columns.Add(deleteButton);
```

Then your CellContentClick could look something similar to that:

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     int check = 0;
     int currentRow = e.RowIndex;

     if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1)
     {
         return;
     }

     if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "Delete" && currentRow >= 0) 
     {
          //do your delete stuff (query a delete query)
     }
     if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "Update" && currentRow >= 0) 
     {
         //do your update stuff (query an update statement)
     }
}
```